# connection refused asp.net with android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json

I have already search a solution with google and try all solutions proposed by all persons but still not resolved!!
I want to connect my android emulator with asp.net my database is in sql server and my error in logcat is:

**E/log tag﹕ erreur dans http connection:Connection to http://10.0.2.2:49948 refused**

when i run my asp.net,firefox show json no problem!! link firefox is: **http://localhost:49948/default.aspx**

my android portion code:

```
//http post
                    try {
                        String nm = un.getText().toString();
                        String pwd = pw.getText().toString();
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        //connect to asp http://127.0.0.1/testadala/default.aspx
                        //String qs = "http://10.0.2.2/LoginApp/default.aspx?name=" + nm + "&password=" + pw;
                        String qs = "http://10.0.2.2:49948/LoginApp/default.aspx?name=" + nm + "&password=" + pw;

                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(qs);
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log tag", "erreur dans http connection:"+e.getMessage());

                    }
```

Thanks for all help!!

Answer (score 0):

First off ensure that your application has been given internet permissions. That is done in the manifest.xml file:

After that, override the header property **host** to **localhost** from **10.0.2.2**. That way, the connection should be accepted by the server (or at least it worked in my case). Unfortunately I've only done this with [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/),but I'm sure you could intercept your request somewhere to achieve this goal.

All the best.

**Edit:** 
On second review, I don't think ASP.NET Web forms will do the job you want. I have never used ASP.NET Web Forms to provide ASP.NET Web Services. You might want to consider using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [WCF](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

And no, the database has nothing to do with the error you are having.

Comment: thanks for your reply!! i have doing these things but still not work!!  my connection string in asp.net is : public class ConnectDB
    {
        private static SqlConnection thisconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost;Database=HerisoaBase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
        public static SqlConnection Model
        {
            get
            {
                return thisconnection;
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in definition of qs, change line 
`String qs = "http://10.0.2.2:49948/LoginApp/default.aspx?name=" + nm + "&password=" + pw;` to 
`String qs = "http://10.0.2.2:49948/LoginApp/default.aspx?name=" + nm + "&password=" + pwd;` 
Check also if this link works in firefox http://10.0.2.2:49948/LoginApp/default.aspx?name=username&password=pass (change name and password).

Comment: the link http://10.0.2.2:49948/LoginApp/default.aspx?name=username&password=pass don't work in my firefox!! i don't know why? i have write 10.0.2.2 because this is the ip default of android

Comment: Why do you use ip adress of android device? You want to connect with web service hosted on localhost, so you should use ip adress of localhost. Use ipconfig to check this adress.

Comment: ok, i have change localhost to ip adress of my machine, and i can see the result like localhost but android is again refused to connect with webservice, why a lot of person can connect and not me!! i have already follow a lot of tutorials (video,web) but no result